# Como concatenar uma lista de um objeto em uma propriedade de outro objeto?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte modelo:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int idUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int Permissao { get; set; }
    public List<Evento> Eventos { get; set; }
}
```

No banco de dados ele é many-to-many, ou seja, Usuario - terceiratabela - Eventos.

Na minha camada de AplicaçãoUsuário possuo a persistência, e tenho um método específico ListarTodos() que faz o select de usuários e chama o método TransformaReaderEmListadeObjetos().

```
    private List<Usuario> TransformaReaderEmListadeObjeto(MySqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var temObjeto = new Usuario()
            {
                idUsuario = int.Parse(reader["idUsuario"].ToString()),
                Email = reader["email"].ToString(),
                Senha = reader["senha"].ToString(),
                Permissao = Convert.ToInt32(reader["permissao"].ToString())
            };
            usuarios.Add(temObjeto);
        }

        reader.Close();
        return usuarios;
```

}

Tá, até ai nenhum problema. Eu quero listar os eventos relacionados ao usuário, ou seja, preciso listar também os eventos dos usuários na terceira tabela. Então, preciso que o modelo Usuário conheça os eventos que ele pertence. Ok.

Ou seja, pela lógica, corrijam me se estiver errado, preciso também de um método ListarTodosComEventos(). Entretanto, se eu crio outro Transformador de Reader em Lista, estarei listando apenas eventos que pertecem a um usuário de Id:x;

Então, preciso concatenar essa lista que criei de usuários para que cada usuário possua sua lista de eventos. *fodeu*

Alguém pode me dar o caminho das pedras para solucionar esse problema? Ou ainda, me esclarecer.

Comment: Não sei se compreendi bem a sua ideia, mas não poderia chamar um método dentro desse método `TransformaReaderEmListadeObjeto` para listar os eventos que o usuário está envolvido? Se você listar os usuários para os eventos e os evnetos para o usuário você entrará em loop. Quando for listar os usuários você deve listar os eventos relacionados ao usuário e quando for listar os eventos, listar os usuário relacionados a ao evento, mas não pode fazer que sempre seja carregado ambos para evitar o loop.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Seguinte, não sei como que está o mapeamento de classe, eu fiz um exemplo básico de como você persistir uma lista genérica em um objeto.

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int idUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int Permissao { get; set; }
    public List<Evento> Eventos { get; set; }
}

public class Evento {

    public int id {get; set;}
    public string descricao {get; set;}
}

public class Main {

    // Lista de eventos.
    List<Evento> lista = new List<Evento>();
    // Cria evento.
    Evento evento1 = new Evento();
    evento1.id = 1;
    evento2.descricao = "Festão do peão";

    EVento evento2 = new Evento();
    evento2.id = 2;
    evento2.descricao = "Rock Brasil";

    // Adicionar eventos na lista.
    lista.Add(evento1);
    lista.Add(evento2);

    // Persistir lista de eventos na tabela de usuário.
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.id = 1;
    usuario.Nome = "João";
    usuario.Email = "joao@email.com";
    usuario.Senha = "123";
    usuario.Permissao = 1;
    // Persistindo lista de eventos no objeto de usuário.
    usuario.Eventos = lista;
}
```